# window.history ( angularJS code ) not storing all the history pages visited in IE 11

Tags: java, angularjs, user-interface, frontend, internet-explorer-11

Here are the urls visited in order

1. www.facebook.com
2. fimst(sso)
3. prodURLAdmin
4. fimst(sso)
5. prodSurveyURL

SO right now i am in 5th which is  URLprodSurveyURL and i am going back from here using a back button  which calls the below function in angular 1.x

```
 $rootScope.goBack = function () {
            if(document.referrer.indexOf("sso/SSO")>-1) {
                var prevPage = -1
                window.history.go(prevPage);
            } else {
                $window.open(document.referrer, '_self');
            }
        };
```

it enters the if loop

**In chrome :**

the windows.history.length is 5 .

window.history.go(-1);

hence here it correctly redirects to prodURLAdmin skipping the fimst(which is sso)

**However in IE 11 :**

after entering the if loop

the windows.history.length is "2" and not 5!

and window.history.go(-1) is redirecting to the very first page i.e www.facebook.com

I am assuming  window.history in IE 11 is only storing two URLs which are:

1. www.facebook.com
2. prodSurveyURL

hence window.history.go(-1) is returning to www.facebook.com

Why is window.history unable to store all the 5 URLS visited  (in order) in IE 11 ?

is this an existing problem ?

is there a workaround or a solution ?

please HELP

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: that's all is the code